# How can I get the count of total distinct rows before paging?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT

    someColumnA,
    someColumnB,

FROM someTable

[A COUPLE JOINS HERE]

[A NICE WHERE STATEMENT]

ORDER BY someColumnA DESC
```

Let's say this query returns 1000 results. When I apply a DISTINCT it will condense down to let's say 300.

What I want to do is only return 10 results using paging to act a preivew to my users and I want to include a total count of the number of DISTINCT ROWS. If I add paging with a count over in the select it will return the number of rows BEFORE THE DISTINCT.

Here is the final query I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT

    count(*) OVER() as total,
    someColumnA,
    someColumnB,

FROM someTable

[A COUPLE JOINS HERE]

[A NICE WHERE STATEMENT]

ORDER BY someColumnA DESC

OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

total = 1000 and not the 300 I want. Is there a simple way to accomplish this or will I have to resort to using a sub select to fetch all 300 distinct rows to then count that and fetch the first 10?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using group by instead of distinct

```
SELECT 
    count(*) OVER() as total,
    someColumnA,
    someColumnB,

FROM someTable

[A COUPLE JOINS HERE]

[A NICE WHERE STATEMENT]

GROUP BY someColumnA, someColumnB
ORDER BY someColumnA DESC

OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CTE**

```
;WITH CTE_Distinct
AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
      someColumnA,
      someColumnB
  FROM someTable
  [A COUPLE JOINS HERE]
  [A NICE WHERE STATEMENT]
)

SELECT
    count(*) OVER() as total, 
    someColumnA,
    someColumnB 
FROM CTE_Distinct
ORDER BY someColumnA DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```